Port Scan Timeout Reached error when deploying Python Dash program to Render
I am getting the error:
Port scan timeout reached, no open ports detected. Bind your service to at least one port. 
If you don't need to receive traffic on any port, create a background worker instead

when trying to deploy my Dash application on Render. I am able to build the program successfully however with my requirements.txt file, so I don't think there should be any issues from building the app itself.
Please see below  a screen cap with the error:

app = dash.Dash()
server = app.server

///Rest of my Code///

#Code to start server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8050))
    host = '0.0.0.0'
    print(f"Starting server on {host}:{port}")
    app.run_server(debug=False, host=host, port=port)

I specified which port to link to in the above code (the default port for Dash), and set my start command as gunicorn plotlyGraph:server (the name of my python file). I tried following some tutorials online but I keep getting the same error despite not seeing any obvious issues with my code/setup, as I was able to deploy it successfully previously on Google Cloud Run.
